# Is there a site that gives travelling opportunities in Europe if you don't care about the destination or the date?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, trains, buses

I'm interested in travelling around Europe the cheapest way possible, but I don't really care about the order in which I visit countries and I'm 100% flexible for both departure and return date.

I'm interested in a site/app that has the following functionality:

It should give me daily/weekly notifications of travelling opportunities from a certain destination to anywhere in any date. (The notification part is not so important, I'm looking for the functionality).

Are there any sites that offer something like that?

Note: It doesn't necessarily have to always be by air.

Comment: I hope the question is on topic, I know asking for the cheapest itself is off-topic but that's not exactly what I'm asking, rather an app that doesn't centre in departure and return dates.

Comment: Europe is rather big! Are there certain countries you want to visit? Certain regions? Some other criteria to decide?

Comment: @Gagravarr that's the thing, I don't care so much. I know I will be departing from Austria, but other than that, I'm open to any possibility. If I had to say something, eastern/northern Europe.

Comment: I don't really get it.  Do you want notifications of flight sales?  Or trains/buses?

Comment: Can you plan your trips a long time in advance (usually the best way to get cheap air/train/bus fares), or are you looking only for last-minute opportunities?

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm open to both.

Comment: Do you mind cycling or hitchhiking? In that case you are really free.

Answer (score 8):

In general I would say there is no such universal resource.

There are websites that can give you nice deals but they are far from complete, they will not give you a route (A->B->C->A). For instance, Ryanair usually does not show up in such planners.

My advise is:

Start by finding a cheap flight somewhere interesting to you. Than you have to start looking from there. You have to check where you can easily go from that place and  if it's worth going. You also have to match that with your interests. I don't see a particular purpose in going somewhere cheap if it has no particular interest to you.
Look at low cost airlines, train connections and bus to find the best deal for each situation.

### Tips:

**Plane**

To search which cities are connected by low cost **plane** companies look in [flycheapo.com](http://www.flycheapo.com/). You can also look directly at ryanair website or easyjet for good deals but flycheapo will give you many more ideas of low cost air-lines.

**Train**

For **train** you have to look yourself in each country. You can also use the [german train website](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/index.shtml). It has some european connections. Central europe is very well connected by train and in many cases it's better than flying (you get out in the city center saving time and avoiding airport transfer costs). Look at the link in "Local public transport route planners" for more train companies websites.

**Bus**

For **bus** I would recomend looking at [eurolines](http://www.eurolines.com/en/). They have very nice deals sometimes.

**Local public transport route planners**

For travelling inside a country you can also check local route planners. These won't exactly give you the cheapest price but wil help you get around in a country. Look at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/is-there-a-list-of-online-public-transportation-planners)

Remember that, in general, if you book in advance you can get better prices.

Answer (score 5):

Travelling around Europe from Austria is as flexible and cheap as an [Interrail](http://www.interrail.eu) or [Eurolines](http://www.eurolines.com/en/eurolines-pass/) pass.

You can go cheaper by [hitchhiking](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Europe).

Some related questions:

- [Interrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrail)
- [Eurolines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=eurolines)
- [Hitchhiking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchhiking)

No site will give you aggregated travelling opportunities competing with these.