# Is there a list of online public transportation planners?

Tags: online-resources, public-transport, planning, london

For Oslo in Norway you can go to [ruter.no](http://ruter.no/en/), punch in where you are and where you want to go. It then gives you options on how to get from point A to point B using various public transportation (and walking).

Is there a list of such services in other countries somewhere? In particular I'm curious to know if there is such a service for London, UK.

Comment: In Poland there is very good site http://jakdojade.pl/Welcome.jsp?locale=en

Comment: For The Netherlands, a good website is http://9292.nl/en#

Comment: For a national site in Norway, consider [rutebok.no](http://rutebok.no).

Comment: Ok, if we're listing them *here*: for whole Finland: http://journey.fi; for Helsinki region: http://reittiopas.fi/en/

Comment: @Jonik How does journey.fi compare to matkahuolto.fi?

Comment: @gerrit: Matkahuolto is for buses only. Journey.fi has "rail and bus connections, flights, walking routes" + local transport for 21 cities.

Comment: Nowadays you also have **Rome2rio**, which covers the whole world (although it is not 100%). In addition, a new app called **Moovel** has been developed, which is also available worldwide, but booking functionality is only available in Germany.

Comment: Why not use Google/Apple/HERE Maps? They're excellent and well integrated with your phone and online services like calendar and assistants. Moovit is good at places where the public transport is very analogue.

Answer (score 21):

## Europe

Below is an incomplete list of domestic public transportation planners. Those usually do not include international transportation, except trains in the case of Bahn.de. Intercity buses may or may not be included, depending on the country.

### Austria

- [oebb.at](http://www.oebb.at/). Similar to the German/Swiss example, although this is actually a railway company, it includes bus-stops. I don't know if it includes *all* public transportation.
- For **Vienna**: Check out the homepage of the "Wiener Linien" and the mobile app WienMobil.

### Finland

- [Journey.fi](http://www.journey.fi/) Rail and bus connections, flights, and walking routes in whole Finland; also local transport connections for 21 cities.
- [Matkahuolto](http://www.matkahuolto.fi/en/) The official resource for buses. Includes the very nice option to not specify a date, and thus find out connections that run only on specific weekdays.
- [VR](http://www.vr.fi/en/index.html) The official resource for all train connections.
- Many cities have their own local transport journey planners: [Helsinki region (Reittiopas.fi)](http://www.reittiopas.fi/en/), [Tampere](http://reittiopas.tampere.fi/en/), [Turku (Föli)](http://www.foli.fi/en), [Oulu](http://www.oulunliikenne.fi/), ...

### France

- [Voyages-sncf](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/) - for trains only, nation-wide. They launch [a new feature](http://mytripset.voyages-sncf.com), quite interesting, for travel by train/plane/car across Europe (it compares them, it does not combine them). For urban transportation, every city has its own system. For Paris region, [ViaNavigo](http://www.vianavigo.com/) is a helpful search engine.
- For **Paris** - [ratp.fr](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/c_21879/visiting-paris/) RATP is the public transportation company operating in the Paris greater metropolitan area.

### Germany

- [Bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/GBR/en/index.shtml). Although Bahn is a railway company, its search engine includes at least buses as well. For example, [here is a search from Strausberger Platz, Berlin to Vallun Chafuol, Zernez](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en?ld=96242&seqnr=1&ident=8e.017232242.1357856408&rt=1&OK#focus) — from a metro station to a bus stop in **Switzerland**. I don't know if it includes *all* public transportation.
- [Busliniensuche.de](http://www.busliniensuche.de/).  It's a search portal that currently offers a search function across 57 companies running one or more bus lines.
- [Busticket.de](http://www.busticket.de/) - another search portal for buses.

### Italy

- [trenitalia.com](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=4ddd1a035296f310VgnVCM1000005817f90aRCRD) - Trenitalia is the Government-owned rail transportation company in Italy
- [italotreno.it](http://www.italotreno.it/EN/Pages/default.aspx) - Italo is a railway service provided by Nuovo Trasporto Viaggiatory. This is a private-owned company founded in 2006 to provide some form of competition to the former Trenitalia monopoly. This helped bring the overall prices down significantly, over the past few years.
- For **Rome** - [atac.roma.it](http://www.atac.roma.it/index.asp?lingua=ENG) ATAC is the public transportation company operating in the Rome greater metropolitan area
- For **Milan** - [atm.it](http://www.atm.it/en/Pages/default.aspx) ATM is the public transportation company operating in the Milan greater metropolitan area

### Liechtenstein

- [lba.li](http://www.lba.li) In Liechtenstein there are no trains, but this site offers an queryable online schedule of the public bus system. This information is also available at [sbb.ch](http://www.sbb.ch).

### Netherlands

- [9292ov.nl](http://9292.nl/en). Includes all public transportation in the Netherlands and combines train, tram, bus and metro in a single itinerary.
- [ns.nl](http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/home). Biggest train company in the Netherlands, also includes information from other railroad companies. This website also shows up-to-date information about delays.

### Norway

- [rutebok.no](http://nri.websrv01.reiseinfo.no/nriiis/Default.aspx?Language=e). Unlike most domestic planners, this includes flights.
- [ruter.no](http://ruter.no/en/) the best for Oslo and surrounding area.

### Poland

- [jakdojade.pl](http://jakdojade.pl/Welcome.jsp?locale=en) - public transport in main Polish cities
- [e-Podróżnik](http://e-podroznik.pl/) - search engine for bus connections between cities. Shows also train connections.
- [BlaBlaCar](https://www.blablacar.pl/bus) - search engine for bus connections between cities both domestic and international. You can buy bus ticket via this site.

### Portugal

- [www.cp.pt](http://www.cp.pt/) Trains all over the country except for the line crossing from Lisbon to Setubal which is operated by another company named Fertagus
- [Transporlis](http://www.transporlis.sapo.pt/Default.aspx?language=en-GB) All transports in Lisbon metropolitan area

### Russia

- [rzd.ru](http://rzd.ru/). Only trains.  Contains quite some trains not listed in HAFAS and also quite some international connections, perhaps also trains in several former Soviet republics — I don't know.
- [eng.rzd.ru](https://eng.rzd.ru/), modern English language version for Russian trains including international connections.

### Spain

- [Renfe](http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/index.html) has a timetable search for trains only, and quite poorly implemented (e.g. at most one change included). From my own experience, Bahn.de and other HAFAS-based sites are often incomplete in Spain. There are many different local companies operating buses; some are included in [Google Transit](http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/#mdy), but some are not; if you're going to a specific city, just try.

### Sweden

- [Resrobot](http://reseplanerare.resrobot.se/bin/query.exe/en?L=vs_resrobot&). In my experience, it does not have all local buses within every town.
- For Stockholm region: [reseplanerare.sl.se](http://reseplanerare.sl.se/bin/query.exe/en?tpl=index&)

### Switzerland

- [sbb.ch](http://www.sbb.ch). Provides schedules for train, bus, and ships all over Switzerland. Also each city is included.

### UK

- [Traveline](http://traveline.info/) has a number of regional journey planners, together covering all of England, Scotland and Wales. Including buses, trains, ferries and flights.
- For London: [Transport for London Journey Planner](http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/)
- For Northern Ireland: [Translink Journey Planner](http://journeyplanner.translink.co.uk)
- For Manchester: [Bus Journey Planner for Manchester](http://manchesterbuses.co.uk)

## Fallback

- For *most* trains in *most* of Europe, any HAFAS-based search engine such as [Bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de/i/view/GBR/en/index.shtml), [B-Rail](http://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/query.exe/E?L=b-rail), or several others. Note that HAFAS is *not* complete. See also [this post on the risks with HAFAS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10599/2509).
- For buses or cities in countries or destinations not listed above, *maybe* [Google Transit](http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/#mdy) works, but more often than not...
- Try googling: `journey planner <city>` or `journey planner <country>`

Comment: Suggest we make this a community wiki answer, and people can add links for each country that  they find?

Comment: @MarkMayo Ok, done.

Comment: @MarkMayo: How about we give this one a **Europe** title and have different CW answers for different chunks of the world. I just started an **Australia** one with the trip planner for Sydney...

Comment: @hippietrail Good idea. I did that and made the countries subtitles.

Answer (score 9):

## North America

[Google Transit](http://www.google.com/intl/en/landing/transit/) offers global transit planning, with very thorough coverage of the U.S. and Canada— in fact, most of the participating agencies use Google in lieu of an independent service. It is accessible in [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/).

[HopStop](http://hopstop.com/) similarly provides trip planning for nearly all major and many minor cities in the U.S. and Canada, and offers iOS, Android, and Windows Phone apps.

### Canada

- [ViaRail](http://www.viarail.ca/en/main) for the train connections in the corridor between Quebec and Vancouver.
- [Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.ca/) for most bus connections (inter-city) west of Montreal, [Orleans Express](https://www.orleansexpress.com/Search.aspx) for some of Quebec and [Maritime Bus](http://www.maritimebus.com) for Atlantic provinces. [Intercar](http://www.intercar.ca/) serves the North-East of Quebec and North coast of St-Lawrence, [Autobus Maheux](http://www.autobusmaheux.qc.ca) the North of Quebec and [multiple other carriers serve parts of Quebec province](http://www.autobusmaheux.qc.ca/fr/cartes/carte-reseau-quebecois.cfm).

#### Local

- Montreal - [STM Trip Planner](http://www2.stm.info/taz/index.php?lng=en)
- Ottawa - [OC Transpo Quick Planner](http://www.octranspo1.com/travelplanner/travelplanner)
- Toronto - [TTC Trip Planner](http://www.ttc.ca/Trip_planner/index.jsp)
- Vancouver - [Translink Trip Planner](http://tripplanning.translink.ca/)

### Mexico

- [TicketBus.com.mx](http://www.ticketbus.com.mx/) for intercity schedules across a variety of bus companies.
- Mexico City (Distrito Federale) - [Metro Origin-Destination](http://www.metro.df.gob.mx/tucamino2/indexing.html) (English)

### Puerto Rico

- San Juan - [Tren Urbano Itinerario](http://www.dtop.gov.pr/itinerario.asp) (Spanish)

### USA

- [Amtrak](http://www.amtrak.com/) for intercity trains in the USA.
- [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.com/) for most intercity bus connections.

#### Local

Most local and regional transit planners are provided by the operating agencies, and may not reflect all options. For example, commuter rail and rapid transit are often administered separately, and a trip planner for one service will often exclude other options.

Northeast

- Baltimore - [MTA Trip Planner](http://mta.maryland.gov/)
- Boston - [MBTA Trip Planner](http://mbta.com/rider_tools/trip_planner/)
- Buffalo - [Metro Trip Planner](http://metro.nfta.com/Trip/trip_planner.asp)
- Connecticut - use Google Transit
- New Jersey - [NJ Transit Trip Planner](http://www.njtransit.com/sf/sf_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=TripPlannerTo)
- New York City - [MTA Trip Planner](http://tripplanner.mta.info/MyTrip/ui_web/customplanner/tripplanner.aspx)
- Philadelphia - [SEPTA Trip Planner](http://airs1.septa.org/bin/query.exe/en?)
- Pittsburgh - [Port Authority Trip Planner](http://www.portauthority.org/paac/SchedulesMaps/TripPlanner.aspx)
- Rhode Island - use Google Transit
- Washington, D.C. - [WMATA Trip Planner](http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/tripplanner/tripplanner_form_solo.cfm)

South

- Atlanta - [MARTA MyCommute](http://mycommute.itsmarta.com/hiwire?.a=iTripPlanning)
- Austin - [CapMetro Trip Planner](http://www.capmetro.org/planner/)
- Charlotte - [CATS Trip Planner](http://tripplanner.ridetransit.org/)
- Dallas - [DART Trip Plan](http://tripplan.dart.org/)
- El Paso - use Google Transit
- Fort Worth - use Google Transit
- Houston - [Metro Trip Planning](http://tripplanner.ridemetro.org/)
- Jacksonville - [JTA Trip Plan](http://tripplan.jtafla.com/HastinfoWeb/TVPOptions.aspx?moniker=Q3JlYXRlVFZQOlRWUE9wdGlvbnM6NWNmMzZmODMtODkyZC00ODllLWE1YjMtYjgwOWFkNGQ1YTg3)
- Louisville - use Google Transit
- Memphis - use Google Transit
- Miami - [Miami-Dade Transit Trip Planner](http://www.miamidade.gov/transit/trip_planner.asp)
- Nashville - use Google Transit
- New Orleans - use Google Transit
- Orlando - use Google Transit
- Raleigh/Durham - use Google Transit
- San Antonio - [VIA Trip Planner](http://www.viainfo.net/BusService/TripPlanWrapper.aspx)
- Tampa Bay - use Google Transit

Midwest

- Chicago - [Goroo](http://goroo.com/goroo/index.htm)
- Cincinnati - use Google Transit
- Cleveland - use Google Transit
- Columbus - use Google Transit
- Detroit - use Google Transit
- Indianapolis - use Google Transit
- Kansas City - use Google Transit
- Minneapolis/St. Paul - [Metro Transit Trip Planner](http://metrotransit.org/tripplanner/)
- St. Louis - use Google Transit
- Tulsa - MILES

West

- Denver - [RTD Trip Planner](http://www3.rtd-denver.com/tripplanner/start.action)
- Honolulu - use Google Transit
- Las Vegas - use Google Transit
- Los Angeles (inc. Orange County and Ventura County) - [go511.com](http://www.go511.com/)
- Phoenix - [ValleyM Metro Trip Planner](http://trips.valleymetro.org/pages/full_trip)
- Portland - [TriMet Trip Planner](http://trimet.org/go/cgi-bin/plantrip.cgi)
- Sacramento - [Regional Transit Trip Planning](http://infoweb.sacrt.com/)
- Salt Lake City - [UTA Trip Planner](http://www.rideuta.com/ridinguta/tripplanner/planner.aspx)
- San Diego - [OTIS Trip Planner](http://www.sdmts.com/tripplanner.asp)
- San Francisco Bay Area - [511.org](http://511.org/)
- Seattle-Tacoma - [Community Transit Trip Planner](http://www.commtrans.org/tripplanner/)
- Spokane - use Google Transit

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a list of such services in other countries somewhere?

**No**, I don't think such a global list exists—at least anything that's comprehensive and up-to-date.

Instead, **your best bet is to simply google**:

```
journey planner <city>
```

This works for pretty much every city that has an online [journey planner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_planner) (also called route planner or trip planner). [Including London](https://www.google.fi/search?q=journey%20planner%20london).

**Update**: The answers to *this question right here* might be the best attempt at such list. :-) Still, they are far from comprehensive (there are *many* cities with a journey planner).

Comment: Yeah, seems like that is the way to go. And helps a lot to know that it's called a "journey planner", which I didn't really know until after asking this :p

Comment: In many countries the journey planners are only available in the language of the country, and not in English.

Comment: In my experience, if one exists, it's usually available in English too. And even if not, you may still *find* it using English search terms (due to how search engines work).

Answer (score 6):

## Australia

**Sydney**

- [NSW TransportInfo "Plan Your Trip"](http://www.131500.com.au/plan-your-trip)
  has more thorough options than Google Maps for Sydney.

**Melbourne**

- [Public Transport Victoria's Journey Planner](http://ptv.vic.gov.au/journey)

Answer (score 5):

You should try [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com). There you can enter a starting point and a destination, and Google Maps calculates routes for you. In most countries. respectively regions, public transport, private motorized traffic, and pedestrian routes are covered.

For example if you want to go from the Buckingham Palace to the Hardrock Cafe in the neighbourhood, Google Maps gives you the following route if you want to travel by car:

[image]

But if you're keen to walk, you get another route:

[image]

Comment: Google Maps' coverage of public transit networks varies. In Berlin, for example, it will only show you S-Bahn routes but nothing utilizing the U-Bahn, buses or trams. I find this actually worse then not providing any service as it may mislead someone to think that the S-Bahn is all that is available.

Comment: That's true. However, Google Maps is the only service that I know that does that for multiple countries (at least rudimentary), as requested by the OP.

Comment: Yeah, that's my experience with Google Maps too. Good for maps, not very reliable for other stuff (unless you live in the US perhaps). Wasn't really after one service which covered multiple countries, but rather a somewhere which listed services for multiple countries. A site that could answer "I want to go to Berlin, what journey planner is good to use there?"

Comment: Any system knowing HAFAS does multiple countries. For example, via [bahn.de](http://bahn.de) one can do trains *and buses* in Germany, Switzerland, and probably other countries do.

Answer (score 4):

Many public transport systems will have similar planners on their website, so that's a good place to start.  eg, if you're in New York, the [MTA website](http://mta.info) has a good route planner.  For London, it's on the [Transport for London website](http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk).

The other option that provides coverage for multiple cities in multiple countries is [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/) which allows you to search for a trip via car, public transport, walking or bicycle - although the exact options will vary depending on the region/city.  Google also has the ability to start or end a trip at "My Location" (just type that into the location box) and it will do it's best to automatically work out exactly where you are.

Answer (score 4):

## The Middle East

**Israel**

*-not including Palestinian territories in the West Bank and the Gaza strip.

*trains*

The train system in Israel is under one national company, so all train times, destinations and prices can be viewed on the [Israel Railways site](http://www.rail.co.il/EN/Pages/Homepage.aspx).

Train tickets are bought at the station, either from a cashier or an automatic machine.

*buses*

There are several bus companies in Israel, most of them operate in different areas. [This site](http://www.bus.co.il/otobusim/Front2007/homepage.asp?LanguageID=20&Design=2007) allows to search for buses from all companies, and has links to all the sites of the different companies. The site gives both lines inside cities and between cities. Includes buses to territories under Israeli control in the west bank.

Tickets are usually bought from the driver in the bus. If you get to the bus in a central station, a ticket can be bought in the station, but isn't mandatory.

The only exception is buses to Eilat. Tickets to Eilat and its surroundings need to be bought in advance on-line or at a central bus station. [Site for Eilat booking](http://www.egged.co.il/Eng/main.asp?lngCategoryID=2771)

*other*

Inside Jerusalem exists a light rail: [their site](http://www.citypass.co.il/english/).

An underground train exists only in Haifa, and it has only six stations, [the Carmelit's site](http://www.carmelithaifa.com/)

Flights are available to/from Haifa, Tel-Aviv and Eilat. Tickets are bought trough the airline site, or through travel agencies or flight booking sites. Sites for the airliners: [El-Al](http://www.elal.co.il/ELAL/English/States/General/), [Arkia](http://www.arkia.com/) and [Israir](http://www.israirairlines.com/).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your query about transport planning for London, "Transport for London" (TfL) has an A to B journey planner available on their website:

http://journeyplanner.tfl.gov.uk/

You can set numerous options including date/time of travel, preferred mode of transport, mobility needs (impaired mobility?) and whether you prefer speed vs convenience (changes/walking distance).

*Note that A and B can be a station, bus stop, postcode (known as zip code in some locations) or 'place of interest'.*

Answer (score 1):

In addition for Australia:

Western Australia
Transperth quite competently covers most of the state for bus, rail and water public transport.

http://www.transperth.wa.gov

Victoria 
Public Transport Victoria- never used it but should cover Victoria
 http://ptv.vic.gov.au

Queensland 
Translink- had to tell the coverage but at least covers the major tourist areas of Cairns and Gold Coast.

http://translink.com.au/

Answer (score 1):

**Japan**

https://world.jorudan.co.jp/mln/en/?sub_lang=nosub

(Never tried this English version, but have used the Japanese version for ca 20 years, works well, and at least nowadays also includes domestic flights) (Often cheaper than train)