# List of carpooling services outside Europe and the US?

Tags: online-resources, hitchhiking, ride-sharing

Europe has a fair share of ad-hoc carpool services like [hitchikers.org](http://www.hitchhikers.org/). So does the US.

But what about the rest of the world? Are there relevant ad-hoc online carpool services out there? So, what about a *list* of such services? Or perhaps just the one service to rule them all?

With 'ad-hoc' I mean services that focus on individual rides, not on structural daily/weekly connections.

Comment: I voted to close, because I think the question is too broad.

Comment: But if he had asked if a *list* of such services exists, then it would've been ok, and possibly people would have built that list *here*? :P [Compare to this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/is-there-a-list-of-online-public-transportation-planners). (Personally I don't have problem with the current form either; maybe it should be CW though.)

Comment: The title of this question makes it sound like it's about services like Germany's well known Mitfahrzentrale / Mitfahrgelegenheit - but the body of the question and the only answer are all about hitchhiking. `\-:`

Comment: You're right, hippietrail. I'm looking for mitfahrzentrale-like services. Also, to mollify the nay-sayers, I've edited the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Hitchwiki.org](http://hitchwiki.org/) exists.

Now when it started, it was more about the 'hitchability' of each country, but it's now evolved to include a forum and groups, so you can try and organise hitching in advance, or meet up with other hitchers.  It covers most countries in the world, and is in multiple languages.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I remember checking that out a long time ago. Super!

Comment: Or not so super. There's not much activity on the hitchwhiki website. It's got the concept down, but seemingly not the users to make it practically usable. What I'd like is something like http://www.hitchhikers.org/ that's used outside of Europe.