# Where to find routes and times of public transportation in Croatia?

Tags: online-resources, public-transport, croatia

Where can I find information about inter-city public transportation in Croatia. I mean buses, trains and maybe ferries?

I need to be able to see information about the route, estimated time, price and changes etc. on the way. Also, the option to buy the tickets on-line ahead of time.

Comment: From the deeper search question is too broad.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Croatia

Comment: It will be easier if you specify a route or a region as you have done for your other question.

Comment: If someone finds an answer, you may wish to post it [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11662/2509).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bus Croatia](http://www.buscroatia.com/) - all bus stations, times and schedules on one website. Also includes ferries.

[Croatia Ferries](http://www.croatiaferries.com/ferry-timetables.htm) - timetables and listings of all ferries within Croatia, and to all the various islands as well.

Trains in Croatia do usually NOT require reservations, except for IC Zagreb - Rijeka/Osijek/Cakovec, and ICN Zagreb to Split.  The fees are about a Euro when made locally.  The official site is [HzNet](http://www.hznet.hr/), however it's in the local language and may be difficult at first to navigate - however, you can jump straight to the [English version of the site](http://www.hzpp.hr/Default.aspx?sec=282).