# Website to plan travel?

Tags: europe, online-resources, planning, western-europe

Is there a good website to plan bus and train transportations in France Benelux and Germany?

Comment: See this question for public transport journey planners, including a few for France and Germany. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11648/is-there-a-list-of-online-public-transportation-planners/11662#11662

Comment: I've removed the bit asking for recommendations of places to travel, as that's considered off topic on Travel.SE (see [help]).

Comment: where would that be ok?

Comment: reddit.com/r/travel is good for it.

Comment: It may be ''good for it'' but it is utterly useless as there is no one there to answer on anything..

Answer (score 2):

You should give the new http://www.goeuro.com/ a try. It doesn't always work on all platforms (browsers), but when it does, their search results are quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

There are two multi-modal travel search engines that I'm aware of that handle this  well. Perhaps you can compare the results to see which one is what you would prefer.

Best worldwide coverage in my view is [Rome2rio](http://rome2rio.com). Here's an example search from [Amsterdam to Hamburg](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Amsterdam/Hamburg). Their coverage in Europe is very comprehensive as data is much easier to come by there than other parts of the world.

The other is [GoEuro](http://www.goeuro.com/) which specifically focusses on Europe. Here's their [Amsterdam to Hamburg results](http://www.goeuro.com/search/NTQwN2I0ZDAyNmUzNDoxMzY1ODQ0NA==) (*I'm unsure whether this is a permalink so apologies if it doesn't work*)

To me the most notable differences would be

1. Rome2Rio offers more options (including rideshare)
2. GoEuro offers more accurate pricing and tighter integration at checkout
3. Rome2Rio returns results faster (the trade-off being less accurate pricing)

Finally, it is worth mentioning [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Amsterdam,+The+Netherlands/Hamburg,+Germany/) can also do this kind of search now, but there is no pricing shown (yet).